# Issue with TurnBased Multiplayer Game in Game-kit

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit

I am working with cocos2d game in which i am implementing Game-kit. My game supports multiplayer option. Actually as given example [Raywenderlich link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1). I am GKTurnBasedMultiplayer class from Game-kit. But now the issue when first player connected to game center and will select option of "Play Now" it automatches for another player. but issue is it directly connects and starts the match, and doesn't wait for another player. I am using

```
[[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:4 viewController:viewConroller];
```

for connecting and playing with other players but directly connects the match.

I want to wait for another player.  That is the issue. I am also using GCTurnBasedMatchHelper Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended functionality of the GameKit API. In a turn-based match, the match data is submitted with the first turn, which in the case of an auto-match, is an undetermined player until Game Center finds an opponent *after* the first submitted turn.

The logic behind this is the "It's always your turn" doctrine with turn-based matches. If Game Center matched you with a player before you submitted your first turn, that other player would be invited to a match in which it wasn't their turn, which is highly undesirable.

As the Apple docs say, you must account for the circumstance of a match participant playerID attribute coming back nil and handle accordingly in your block code. The opponent will be nil until you receive their turn (which naturally occurs after the creator's first turn). If you are still confused by this, reference the [Turn-Based Game Center API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW1).